# Creating custom webview in maui 6/7

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

Im trying to find out a way on how my page successfully loaded on webview.

(Or even had an error or timeout)

there is a code on SO for this :

```
webView.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

...

    public class CustomWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public CustomWebViewClient()
        {
        }
    
        public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
    
            // Your Logic comes here
        }
    }
```

but when im using normal webview in my application and it dont have "SetWebViewClient".

how can i make a custom webview that inherits from WebViewClient ?

i want to implement error handling and loader into this custom webview handler.

normal webView uses **Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebView** but WebViewClient uses **Android.Webkit.WebView** namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a [Customize controls with handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize) to achieve this.

Suppose we define a webview in xaml:

```
<WebView x:Name="mywebview" Navigating="mywebview_Navigating" WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="400" Source="https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui" />
```

When navigating to a new page, fire the Navigating event handler in code-behind:

```
CustomWebViewClient customWebViewClient = new CustomWebViewClient();

void mywebview_Navigating(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
#if ANDROID
    (this.mywebview.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView).SetWebViewClient(customWebViewClient);
    
#endif
}
```

In Platform/Android folder, you may create your CustomWebViewClient. For example:

```
using WebView = Android.Webkit.WebView;

public class CustomWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    public CustomWebViewClient()
    {
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);

        // Your Logic comes here
    }

    public override void OnReceivedHttpError(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse)
    {
    //get error from errorResponse  
        base.OnReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
    }

}
```

You may set a breakpoint at your logic and see if it works.

---

**Another way that may be helpful**:

The webview also has Navigated event:

```
<WebView x:Name="mywebview" Navigated="mywebview_Navigated" .../>
```

And in event handler, you could implement your logic based on the type of **WebNavigationResult**.

```
void mywebview_Navigated(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Result)
    {
        case WebNavigationResult.Cancel:
            // your logic
            break;
        case WebNavigationResult.Failure:
            // your logic
            break;
        case WebNavigationResult.Success:
            // your logic
            break;
        case WebNavigationResult.Timeout:
            // your logic
            break;
        default:
            // your logic
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!